# Don't know how to get user data after oAuth Dialog

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

i'm developing a FB app.
The app is authenticating within a canvas page, redirect to OAuth Dialog upon page load

```
if(!isset($data['user_id']) && $data['page']['liked']){ ?>
<script>
  var oauth_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/';
  oauth_url += '?client_id=XXXX';
  oauth_url += '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent('https://apps.facebook.com/YYYY/');
  window.top.location = oauth_url;
</script>
<?php   
}
```

When the user authenticate i just need to read the Name of the User, but i can't find that info into the signed_request.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You need to use the access token you receive and make calls to the API with it; I see nothing there suggesting you've done so

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following steps:

1. Decode the signed request as mentioned [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/).
2. Extract the access token.
3. Make a new request with the extracted access token to retrieve the user's name.

Comment: Thanks Yan, step 1 ok;  step 2 ok; step 3 - how did i submit that request? do i need the php sdk (or javascript sdk)?

Comment: Use PHP SDK for the 3rd step.

Comment: with the getUser() function i suppose... but it doesn't accept parametrs, how can i send the token?

Comment: prior to your request you can do the following: `facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);`

Comment: You are welcome. If you find this answer helpful, please select it as the right answer.